# How to delete file with admin privledges using Python

Tags: python, permissions, admin, shutil

I have tried to use **shutil.move()** to move a collection of files individually from their directory in one drive to another drive and it appears to succeed on *copying* the first file, however when it comes to delete the remove it runs into a **permission error**:

```
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Program Files\\openPDC\\Archive\\ppa_archive_2020-03-04 15!25!29.120_to_2020-03-04 20!16!30.900.d'
```

I am able to manually delete the file by hand using **admin privledge** but I am unsure on how to invoke admin privledge within the Python script to allow the shutil.move() to the remove the original file. I have tried to remove the read-only access but that doesn't seem to help, any ideas?

```
            try:
                os.chmod(files[i], stat.S_IWRITE )
                os.unlink(files[i])
                shutil.move(files[i], destination)
            except PermissionError:
                print ("Error: Could not move file {} from {} to {}".format(files[i], source, destination))
                raise
```

Comment: `shutil` may not have this functionality and you may have to run code which runs standrad `move` or `remove` with admin privileges - on Linux you could run code with `sudo` to execute as admin - `os.system("sudo mv ...")`. OR maybe you should run all script as admin.

Comment: I have attempted using other functions such as ```copy``` and ```remove```, ```copy``` works fine but ```remove``` still causes a permission error. I have attempted to run the whole script as admin but haven't had any luck.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue, rather than over complicate the code I found it easiest to go into the original directories **Properties -> Security -> Edit** and then select my user group and allow full control of the files within the directory.

After that moving the files caused no issue.

Comment: this worked for me on windows 11.